# LC-3 Assembly Subtract Two Numbers

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am having problem with this question as I am new to LC-3 programming.

Write a LC-3 code to subtract the value in R1 from the value in R0 and place the result in R5. That is, write the assembly code for R5 := R0 - R1. Assume R1=10 and R0 is 12.

Answer (score 2):

Per your question, we can assume that 12 and 10 are already in `R0` and `R1`, so the correct algorithm starts at the `NOT` instruction and ends at `HALT`; however, the other instructions are included to allow you to run this code.

The solution is to add `R0` with `-R1`. We find `-R1` by doing bitwise inversion (`NOT`) on the number in `R1` and adding 1.  This gives us the 2's complement negation of R1.

If you do not understand two's complement arithmetic, I suggest looking [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html#operations). After the subtraction in performed, we restore the original number to `R1`.

```
.orig x3000

LD R0, A        ; A(12) => R0 (this is assumed)
LD R1, B        ; B(10) => R1 (this is assumed)
                ; find negative of the two's complement number in R1
NOT R1, R1
ADD R1, R1, 1
ADD R5, R0, R1  ; R0 - R1 => R5
LD R1, B        ; Restore R1
HALT

A .fill 12
B .fill 10

.end
```

Comment: hey Tyler, I run the program but it is not showing any output. My LC-3 console window only displays" Halting the Processor".. will you please inform why it is displaying that statement?.

Comment: As I understand it, the program should not show any output (on the console, at least). The instructions were to "place the result in R5."

Comment: Ohh okay... Tyler Thank you for your help,,, :)

Comment: Instead of destroying R1 and reloading, you could NOT into R5 to produce `R5 := ~R1`, and so on from there.